# Characterisation of exact sequence in abelian category

Tags: category-theory, exact-sequence, abelian-categories

First of all, thank you to everyone for helping!

So, I am currently familiarizing myself with category theory, in particular with abelian categories. In MacLane's *Categories for the Working Mathematician* he gives the following characterisation of an exact sequence in an abelian category.

"A sequence $A \overset{f}{\rightarrow} B \overset{g}{\rightarrow}C$ is exact at $B$ if and only if $gf = 0$ and to every $z \in_m C$ there exists a $y \in_m B$ with $gy \equiv z$" (Theorem 3 (v), p. 205)

where $x \in_m X$ denotes a *member* of $X$, i.e. an equivalence class of the equivalence relation $\equiv$ induced by the partial ordering $\leqq$, where we have that $x \leqq y$ for two morphism with codomain $X$ if and only if there exists a morphism $z$ such that $x$ factors through $y$, i.e., $x = yz$.

When he proves that the condition on the members together wit $gf = 0$ implies that the sequence is exact at $B$, he uses the mono-epic factorisation $f = me$ and states

"Conversely, given this property of all $y \in_m B$, take $k = \text{ker }g$; then $k\in_m B$ and $gk = 0$. Therefore there is a member $x \in_m A$ with $fx \equiv k$; that is, with $ku = mexv$ for suitable epis $u$ and $v$."

So far, everything is clear for me, but then he goes on

"But this equation implies that the monic $k$ factors through $m$, and hence that $\text{im }f \geqq \text{ker }g$."

And here comes my question: why can he deduce that $k$ factors through $m$ because so far we only know that $ku$ factors through $m$? How can he get rid of the $u$ on the left-hand side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the epi-mono factorization $ex = nw$ (where $n$ is mono and $w$ is epi). Then the equation $ku = mexv = (mn)(wv)$ gives two epi-mono factorizations of a single morphism, so we must have $k\cong mn$ as objects over $b$, i.e., $k$ factors through $m$.